# Como atualizar página web "Modal" sem dar refresh (F5) após acescentar ultima informação?

Tags: php, angularjs

Esse é meu código do arquivo *Modal*

```
$scope.salvarObservacao = function (data) {
    if(data.dsObservacaoEvento === undefined | data.dsObservacaoEvento === '' ) {
        alert('Campo obrigatório.');
        return false;
    }

    EventoService.salvarObservacao($rootScope.idEvento,data).then(function(dados){
        toaster.pop('success','Participantes','Dado salvo com sucesso.');

        // toaster.pop ({
        //     type: 'success',
        //     title: 'Participantes',
        //     body: 'Dado salvo com sucesso.',
        //     onHideCallback: function () { 
        //         $modalStack.dismissAll();
        //     }
        // });
    }).catch(function(err){
        //...
    });

    setTimeout($modalStack.dismissAll(),3000);
};

}],
templateUrl: 'modal/incluir-observacao.html'
}

});
```

Comment: Boa tarde Leufrasio, Como está o seu template? Dependendo do caso, se entendi direito sua pergunta, você tem uma lista de observações, e a cada atualização você quer que a mesma atualize em tela. Assumindo que você tenha uma lista de observações que você itera via ng-repeat basta chamar o método que lista as observações novamente ou incrementar esta lista com o novo dado inserido. O angular por ser bi-direcional irá atualizar automaticamente as informações em tela. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/databinding. Caso este modal seja carregado dentro de um iframe, uma solução seria via javascript

Comment: Boa tarde Leufrasio, Como está o seu template? Dependendo do caso, se entendi direito sua pergunta, você tem uma lista de observações, e a cada atualização você quer que a mesma atualize em tela. Assumindo que você tenha uma lista de observações que você itera via ng-repeat basta chamar o método que lista as observações novamente ou incrementar esta lista com o novo dado inserido. O angular por ser bi-direcional irá atualizar automaticamente as informações em tela. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/databinding. Caso este modal seja carregado dentro de um iframe, uma solução seria via javascript

Comment: No sistema eu tenho um campo ''incluir observação', eu preciso que ao salvar esta ''observação'', no botão 'observação' surgir um hint mostrando esta última informação sem precisar dar refresh na página.
Poderia me encaminhar uma linha de código como exemplo, pfv ??

Comment: Não sei se entendi direito como você quer que exiba essa hint, pelo que você descreveu agora, é apenas um toast para dizer que os dados foram atualizados ? Não seria apenas uma mensagem registrando o sucesso da operação?

Comment: Não Almer, isso está acontecendo com sucesso, segue assim na página: 'incluir observação' > abre a janela para editar > clico em salvar > surge a msg que foi salvo com sucesso > retorna para a página onde pode incluir novamente uma observação... mas no canto direito há um ícone que ao posicionar o mouse nele é onde deverá aparecer o hint com esta nova observação que salvei, mas preciso que ela apareça sem precisar dar refresh. A nova observação editada só surge no hint depois que pressiono F5 !!...deu pra compreender melhor assim  ?... aguardo...

Comment: Agora entendi. Então tente o seguinte: no callback do seu modal, atualize o escopo do angular com $scope.apply(); Apenas certifique que este está sendo chamado após os dados serem salvos.